# How to declare parameter as function without return value?

Tags: kotlin

I have a function in kotlin

```
fun printExecutionTime(block: () -> Any) {
    run {
        val currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
        block()
        Logr.d("Execution time of " + block.javaClass.name + " -> " + System.currentTimeMillis().minus(currentTimeMillis))
    }
}
```

In java code, I want to pass void reference function as parameter, but can't bcs of return value

```
PerformanceKt.printExecutionTime(this::voidFunc);
```

One way will be to use interface

```
interface Action {
    fun call()
}
```

Is it possible to declare it in kotlin without an extra interface, so the code above will work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried using [`Unit`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-unit/index.html)?

```
fun f(voidFunc: () -> Unit) {
    // <...>
}
```

---

**upd:** After some googling I should admit, that this solution won't work for you. There's an open [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-12455) covering the use of **Java** method references with **Kotlin** functional types.

However, there's still a workaround to use in **Java** (looks ugly, yes):

```
public Unit voidFunc() {
    // <...>
    return null;
}
```

Comment: are you sure you can ? `Unit` only support function return type, don't support parameters. Indeed, it actually a generic parameter of `Function0`, so you can't solve the OP's problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can using `java.lang.Runnable` to avoiding introduce additional interface ,for example:

```
fun printExecutionTime(block: Runnable) {
  run {
    val currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
    block.run()
    //...
  }
}
```

then you can using java method reference expression as below:

```
PerformanceKt.printExecutionTime(this::voidFunc);

void voidFunc(){...}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `Runnable` or a `Consumer` **if i had to use that function in java code too** (otherwise i would use `Unit` as pointed by other anwers)

```
fun doIt(person:Consumer<String>, action: Runnable){
    person.accept("A message")
    action.run();
}
```